# Node.js - file write returning a file with 0 KB

Tags: javascript, node.js, io

The following code to write a string to a specified file is returning a file with a size of 0 KB. This function was working yesterday, but it stopped working today for some unknown reason.

```
fs.writeFile(location + 'file.txt', stringToWrite, function (err)
{        
  if (err) {
    console.log('Log 1: Error Thrown - ' + err);
  }
  console.log('Log 2: File Write Success');
});
console.log('Log 3: After File Write');
```

The lines Log 1 and Log 2 never display. Log 3 will display however.

I can verify that stringToWrite does contain a string that can be written to the file. I can also verify that the location is correct, as a file is written there, however with a size of 0 KB (empty file).

Is there a sort of limit to the number of characters that can be written by fs.writeFile? Or is it something else altogether? The fact that Log 1 and Log 2 aren't even displaying makes me feel it's something else altogether, although I don't know what.

Comment: Start with something simple: change `stringToWrite` to a constant, simple value (`'12345'`), and do the same with the filename (`c:\\1.txt`). If that fails, do it from a separate project / process that doesn't have anything else going on. report back :-)

Comment: Verify that the permissions didn't change either, or that the file location isn't on a remote mount point that might have been unmounted.

Comment: Hello, the file is being written to a local directory. I've tried using a constant text, and a constant filename, but the file is still returning a 0 KB file.

Comment: @JulianWenHsiLee Hi, the problem could be because of asynchronous nature of the function itself. Is it possible for you to use method `fs.writeFileSync`?

Comment: Are you sure there's no error thrown? Being async, "Log 3" might have been output before an unhandled error was thrown (as you probably know, your printout "After File Write" is misleading since you're making that print immediately after calling the function, not when it's completed).

Did you try deleting the file before? Could it exist already but with improper access rights for your program to write to?

Comment: @JHH I have deleted the file and tried regenerating it - all I got was a file with 0 KB size.

Yes I specifically wrote Log 3 there just so something would appear regardless of whether the function did work or not. I've read a suggestion saying I should try wrapping the file write function in a try catch block so I will try that next.

Comment: @kucing_terbang Why on earth would you recommend someone to use the synchronous function instead of finding the root cause? Unless this is a local program not serving requests etc (i.e., being a server), using sync fs operations is strongly discouraged. But sure, as a step in the debugging you might want to try it, not as a solution though.

Comment: @Julian Right, wrapping in a try/catch was what I would recommend as well.

For example if you're using promises and there's a missing done() call somewhere, or if you have a catch/fail clause further up the call chain that just silently swallows the error, it might appear as if the program is simply hanging.

Comment: @JHH I've tried try catch, but it's also returning nothing...

Comment: @JHH well, I think I'm not make it obvious enough that I just want to check if the function able to produce the file or not.If the function able to produce the file, then the problem is not on the permission, file space or stuff like that.

Comment: @kucing Right, I agree. As a step in debugging it makes perfect sense. But like I said, I interpreted your advice as a recommendation to abandon the async methods in favor of the sync ones. I'm glad we sorted that out. ;)

Comment: Hey guys, I seem to have resolved the issue. To give a bit more context, I am using a CSS post-processor to apply a bunch of fallback styling for a stylesheet for legacy browsers, then having it be written out to a specific CSS file. Hence why I was trying to write it to a new file (which is what stringToWrite represents). However, I tried to write out my file using Node.js's file write function, since grunt (the CSS compiler) works off Node.js). I have switched to grunt's in-built write function - grunt.file.write - and it's now working. So I cannot say what the issue was.